# Applying same style to multiple elements

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I am new to using WPF and I was trying to apply `Style` (e.g. Background for `TextBox`, `Button` and `MenuItem` should be Orange). To achieve this I did something like:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="sampleTextBox">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11px"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFD190" Offset="0.2"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Orange" Offset="0.85"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFD190" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and repeated the same piece of code for targettype `Button` and for target menu.
This is working absolutely fine. But I would like to minimize the amount of repeated code by probably having multiple targettype values.

Please let me know if it is possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
  <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="sampleTextBox">
        <Setter Property="Control.FontFamily" Value="Verdana"/>
        <Setter Property="Control.FontSize" Value="11px"/>
        <Setter Property="Control.FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="Control.Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFD190" Offset="0.2"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Orange" Offset="0.85"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFD190" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="This is a string and it should be wrapped." Style="{StaticResource sampleTextBox}"/>
    <TextBox Text="This is a string and it should be wrapped." Style="{StaticResource sampleTextBox}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying this from a long time. did not know removing targettype will do the magic :)

Comment: @Deeksha You should also look into the `BasedOn` property of `Style`. I'm sure you'll find it useful sooner or later. +1 to otis23's answer

Answer (score 3):

Style has an attribute *BasedOn*. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon.aspx With this you can use Style inheritance. Define a base style with common attributes and derive your child styles with specific attributes.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `FrameworkElement` as a `TargetType`:

```
<Style TargetType="FrameworkElement" x:Key="CommonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Control.Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFD190" Offset="0.2"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Orange" Offset="0.85"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFD190" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And then use specific styles for each element by [inheriting (BasedOn)](http://wpftutorial.net/StyleInheritance.html) `CommonStyle`:

```
<Style TergetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource CommonStyle}" x:Key="TextBoxStyle">
     <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
     <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana"/>
     <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11px"/>
     <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this method but it says Background is not a valid property on FrameworkElemnt. Only margin on FrameworkElement was applicable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes using it with Control.Background/any property did fix my problem.